# How to use App Access Token to update Open Graph Tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-graph-api

I want to dynamically update Open Graphs Tags on my website, but don't know how to do it properly.

I have understood you're not supposed to use the access token in a client side script, but how do I go about and update it otherwise.

I have seen examples online that does not use an access token, but I get an authorization error then.

Can I make any settings on facebook developer to skip access token or how can I make a call from my javascript, without showing the access token or app secret?

---

This is the part of my script which runs after modifying the meta:og tags:

```
//Update Open Graph
$.post(
'https://graph.facebook.com',
{
    access_token: '123',
    id: strCurrentUrl,
    scrape: true
},
function(response){
    console.log(response);
}
```

From Facebook:

> for security, app access token should never be hard-coded into
>   client-side code, doing so would give everyone who loaded your webpage
>   or decompiled your app full access to your app secret, and therefore
>   the ability to modify your app. This implies that most of the time,
>   you will be using app access tokens only in server to server calls.

Comment: you should not update them anyway, after a while they even get locked. open graph tags should not change at all in general.

Comment: what is best practice then for sharing content that is loaded after page load, and therefore cannot be in the meta tags from page load?

Comment: you HAVE to provide them in the initial html, without javascript. it is always possible, just do stuff server side instead.

Comment: how can I load them in the initial html when the content is loaded after the page load?

Comment: what´s the content? you need to be more specific. what exactly are you doing right now?